# What bulb should I use in 4" recessed lights?

Tags: led, recessed-lighting, bulb, halogen

I have Halo H99ICAT housings with a variety of trims and am confused on what bulbs I can use.

The label inside the can states that I can use specified bulbs with the following trims-

953P Black Baffle - 50WPAR20 with socket extension (H1999)

990P Pinhole - 50WPAR20 or 50WR20

1420 Slot Aperture - 50W 12V MR16

I currently have 50W MR16 Halogen with a GU10 base that gives me the light I want on the wall, however I think configuration will over lamp if left on too long.

1. Is the socket extension for the 953P for heat (get the bulb away from the top of the can) or more to extend the light source?
2. I don't understand why I need a 50W 12V MR16 for the 1420 Slot Aperture when I can use a 50WPAR20 in the 990P Pinhole which has a smaller opening.
3. When they state 50W, I am assuming that is based on heat output, but what wattage rating do you use for LED? The actual LED wattage or the incandescent equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The 953P does not come with a socket extension. I'm not sure where you got it or why. With an H99 I can't see the use of one.
2. You CANNOT use a 12v MR16 in an H99 can. In fact, the 1420 trim is not for use with the H99 series. It is ONLY for use with the H1499 series low voltage housings.
   See here: http://www.cooperindustries.com/content/dam/public/lighting/products/documents/halo/spec_sheets/HR_ADV110509_990trim_spec.pdf
3. Yes, 50 watts is the incandescent wattage limit. The CFL or LED equivalent does not apply.

Comment: Thanks SPEEDY PETEY, @PeterSmith
1. The 953P did not come with the extension, I read somewhere that I needed it, but I may have been mistaken as I cannot find it now.
2. It looks to me that I cannot use a slot baffle with the H99 since Halo only officially makes it for the H1499. Does anyone know of a slot baffle I could use?